# Renaming files in unix of particular date

Tags: linux, unix

`for filename in $*;  do mv "$filename" "${filename//.temp/}";`

I am using this script to rename files.
It removes .temp from filename. I have saved this as `a.sh` script and execute it with the files I want to rename. But this becomes tedious if I want to rename say 100 files and only of particular date. is there a way I pass only date with the script as a parameter and it renames files of that date only without having me to pass the filenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `a.sh` like this :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.temp" -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0//.temp/}' {} \;
```

`newermt` is for the date the file is modified last time.

and can execute it as

`./a.sh 2017-09-27`

To test if this command works on command line, you can try this outside your script:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.temp" -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0//.temp/}' {} \;
```

Comment: getting this error >  mv: invalid option -- 'a'  . I used the last command to check

Comment: Try now, I've changed double quotes to single.

Comment: I used this >>> find . -type f -newermt 2017-10-03 ! -newermt 2017-10-04 -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0//.temp/}' {} \; >>>>your command was renaming all the files. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: and one more case that this command should not check the subfolders. I am trying to use depth/max-depth getting errors. Currently the above commands checks all the sub-folders

Comment: @Ritesh: Yes it was checking all the file. I've updated my answer to match files only having ".temp" in their name. I've included maxdepth 1 to check in current directory only. Try and let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: modified to this >>> find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.temp" -newermt 2017-08-15 ! -newermt 2017-08-16 -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0//.temp/}' {} \; >>>> your thoughts!!

Comment: so just out of curiosity, is it possible to range this within a timeframe on that date?? eg: 2017-08-16 10:00 to 2017-08-16 12:00

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use `-nt` test

```
# create a timestamp file
timestamp_filename=/tmp/$$
touch -t 201709270000 "$timestamp_filename"
trap 'rm "$timestamp_filename"' EXIT

# then to check a file is newer
if [[ "$a_file" -nt "$timestamp_filename" ]]; then
# a_file is newer
fi
```